# Ошибка при работе с файлами

Tags: c++

Помогите понять в чем ошибка.
Задание:

> Сделать поиск файлов в введенном каталоге, созданных в промежутке времени от 8:45 до 11:15

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int catalogCount = 0; //количество каталог
    _finddata_t data; //поиск имени файла
    char path[255]; //указываем каталог
    struct tm newtime;

    //ввод каталога
    cout << "Введите каталог: "; cin >> path;

    intptr_t handle = _findfirst(path, &data); //_findfirst ищет каталог файла или подкаталог
    do
    {
        if (data.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) //attrib - атрибут файла
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //указываем имя и время создания
            localtime_s(&newtime, &data.time_create);
            if ((newtime.tm_hour == 8 && newtime.tm_min >= 45) || (newtime.tm_hour == 9 || newtime.tm_hour == 10) || (newtime.tm_hour == 11 && newtime.tm_min <= 15))
            {
                cout << catalogCount + 1 << ". " << data.name << " - file" << endl;
                cout << newtime.tm_mday << "." << newtime.tm_mon + 1 << "." << newtime.tm_year + 1900 << " " << newtime.tm_hour << "." << newtime.tm_min << endl;
                cout << endl;
                catalogCount++;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }

    } while (_findnext(handle, &data) == 0);

    if (catalogCount == 0)
        cout << "Каталог не существует!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Количество каталогов равно = " << catalogCount << endl;

    _findclose(handle); //конец работы с поиском файла

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где же сама ошибка? или это новый вид вопросов - угадайте, где именно у меня ошибка:)

Comment: попробуйте убедится, что в каталоге есть подходящие файлы, а на запрос программы вводите где то так "C:\User\Name\*.*"

Comment: @KoVadim, такая ошибка вылетает (закинул в описание)

Comment: Эта ошибка воспроизводится на любом каталоге или на каком то конкретном?

Comment: @KoVadim, теперь не может найти каталог 
при записи С:\rdmnd*.*

Comment: там закралась очепятка - слеш пропущен - `C:\rdmnd\*.*`

Comment: @KoVadim, теперь снова та же ошибка, что в описании вопроса

Comment: @KoVadim, во всех каталогах

Comment: проверьте, что возвращается здесь `intptr_t handle`. я код у себя запускал и он отработал как я того ожидаю. Чудес не бывает, что то у Вас немного не так.